# HighCharts Tooltips are coming but Graph is not coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I had include the jquery 1.8.2 and highcharts 2.1.2 any thing i missed ?

How can i resolve it..only tooltips are coming but not the graph

[image]

Comment: could you please share the code snippet, which would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Go through this issue https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the Highchart with 3.0 works for me..Sebastian Bochan also answered same thing

Answer (score 1):

In case when you upgrade jquery, you should also upgrade your Highcharts. So I advice to use jquery 1.8.2 with Highcharts 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a datetime x-axis you need to have your data in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the jQuery 1.8.2 with jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem few days back. I was using jQuery 1.8. After quite a bit of time on that, I replaced the jQuery file with jQuery 1.7. It worked like a charm for me.